# Simple html dom file_get_html not working - is there any workaround?

Tags: php, html-parsing, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');

    //base url
    $base = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps';

    //home page HTML
    $html_base = file_get_html( $base );

    //get all category links
    foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $element->href );
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    $html_base->clear(); 
    unset($html_base);

?>
```

I have the above code and I'm trying to get certain elements of the Play Store page but it isn't returning anything. Is it possible that certain PHP functions might be disabled on the server to stop that?

The above code works perfectly on other sites.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Working fine for me tho...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As I said, your example is working fine for me... But try this way using curl instead:

```
//base url
$base = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Create a DOM object
$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html_base->load($str);

//get all category links
foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element->href );
    echo "</pre>";
}

$html_base->clear(); 
unset($html_base);
```

It gets all the links as expected:

[image]

And make sure you have `php_openssl` and `php_curl` installed...

Comment: wow thank you, as you said, I just needed to activate the "php_openssl" extension and it works now :) I'm using WAMP Server on windows and it was inactive by default. Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

remove the semicolon from php.ini and restart Apache server to enable php module configuration

```
; Windows Extensions
...
;extension=php_openssl.dll
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set "allow_url_fopen" as TRUE in "php.ini" to allow accessing files via HTTP or FTP.
Some hosting venders disable PHP's "allow_url_fopen" flag for security issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
$post = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($post,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($post,CURLOPT_URL,$website);
curl_setopt($post,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($post,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"regno=$Number");
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);
curl_getinfo($post, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$curlresponse = curl_exec($post);
curl_close($post);  
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($curlresponse);
```

DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced 
THIS IS URL : http://www.annauniv.edu/cgi-bin/result/cgrade.pl?regno=11210104001