# file_get_html() doesnt work

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have very basic script that should load html of given website and print out all links it finds in code, its just an example, however I cant get it working and cant figure out why.
code:

```
<?php
$html=file_get_html("http://www.google.com/");
foreach($html->find("a") as $element)
echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```

It returns blank page, $html is just empty
I found it might be problem of openssl but I have openssl enabled and its not working anyway. I use apache 2.2.14 on Ubuntu and php 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18 is version I have currently installed.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need to add/require/whatever your `SimpleHTMLDomParser`

Comment: It would not matter. Check if the HTML is valid...?

Comment: `file_get_html` isn't a built-in PHP function.

Comment: It looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668562/1519058

Comment: @JohnConde This isn't a duplicate because Ruli does not see an error, just a blank return.