# other method of handle errors in simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

This is a simple code: (simple html dom)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com');

$title = $html->find('div.newsBody h1', 0)->plaintext;
echo "Title:". $title;
```

If div.newsBody dosen't exist in google page we get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

Now I want to handle this error:

```
 if(file_get_html('http://google.com'))
 { 
     $html = file_get_html('http://google.com');
     if($html->find('div.newsBody h1', 0))
         echo $html->find('div.newsBody h1', 0)->plaintext;
     else
         echo "No div found!";
 }
 else
     echo "No webpage Access!";
```

Is it true? or IS there a better solution?

Comment: Use `cURL` instead... Check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668562/1519058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it's done, but don't repeat yourself:

```
if($div = $html->find('div.newsBody h1', 0))
  echo $div->plaintext;
```