# Multiple page scraping

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm looking for a method to make the following script scrape multiple pages located in an array and write the selected content into a text or excel document.

Any ideas? 
Is this possible? 
And another question would be why the script works on localhost but not when placed on the server. Thank you.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
function scraping() {
    // create HTML DOM

    $html = file_get_html('http://lmvz.anofm.ro:8080/lmv/detalii.jsp?UNIQUEJVID=50/01/1150001435/1&judet=50');

    // get article block
    if($html && is_object($html) && isset($html->nodes)){

    foreach($html->find('/html/body/table') as $article) {
        // get title

        $item['titlu'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[1]/td/div', 0)->plaintext);

        // get body
        $item['tr2'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr3'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr4'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr5'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr6'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr7'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr8'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr9'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr10'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
        $item['tr11'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]', 0)->plaintext);
         $item['tr12'] = trim($article->find('/tbody/tr[12]/td/div/]', 0)->plaintext);
       $ret[] = $item;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;}
}
echo '<pre>';
$ret = scraping();


foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo $v['titlu'].'<br>';

    echo $v['tr2'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr3'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr4'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr5'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr6'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr7'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr8'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr9'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr10'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr11'].'<br>';
    echo $v['tr12'].'<br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the result of $html when it's deployed to the server?

Comment: When placed on server, it turns up blank. Otherwise on localhost the script works perfectly.

Comment: Try curl instead of file_get_html : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667441/simple-html-dom-file-get-html-not-working-is-there-any-workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl would give you cleaner output, you could try using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) to make the code easier to write, it should support all the functionality you need.

In terms of writing to Excel, there is a great PHP library to write to Excel in PHP - [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Or if you want to write to a text file, thats event easier, just combine all the text you want into a string and run `file_put_contents('PATHTOFILE', $multiPageContents);`, just make sure the filepath you are pointing to is writable by the user running PHP.