# 500 Error on bluemix with simple-html-dom

Tags: db2, simple-html-dom, ibm-cloud

I'm hoping someone can help me here. I'm using simple html dom to get some data from a website and everything works fine on my local PC, but i get the 500 internal server error in the console when I uploaded to the ibm bluemix. I have tried tried to add the solution here

[Simple html dom file_get_html not working - is there any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667441/simple-html-dom-file-get-html-not-working-is-there-any-workaround)

It doesn't work...like I said it works fine on my localhost. With same database connection and everything

Comment: Go run 'cf logs <app name> and let's us know what you find. You can't solve a problem if you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Can you please post some more information about what you are trying to do?  As is the question is not a programming question.  Stackoverflow is a community on asking programming questions and showing what you have tried to get help.

Comment: Thanks Jeff Sloyer, what i finally did won't probably make sense to you but it works now. I tried the cf logs <appnam> as suggested by jpapejr and got no error. The page just returns blank page, so i started debbuggiing bit by bit, it was a php error after all, i set an array $publications = []; and bluemix didn't like so i used unset($publications) instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getting what you described in your comment,

```
$publications = [];
```

is not the right sintax for empty/reset a PHP array and this is the reason for having error 500.

The right PHP way to do it is

```
$publications = array();
```

You can use also

```
$publications = null;
```

but you then have to check if null when using it again or

```
unset($publications);
```

like you have already done, but keep in mind that it destroys the var so you have to initialize it again later.

Comment: Yeah i figured. Somehow it works on my localhost. I'm going with $publications = array() now. Cheers