# file_get_html returns null in live server but works fine in localhost

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I was using following code to scrap a web page it works normally on localhost but returns

```
require_once('advanced_html_dom.php');

$dom = file_get_html('http://exams.keralauniversity.ac.in/Login/index.php?reslt=1');

$rows = array();
foreach($dom->find('tr.Function_Text_Normal:has(td[3])') as $tr){
  $row['num'] = $tr->find('td[2]', 0)->text;
  $row['text'] = $tr->find('td[3]', 0)->text;
  $row['pdf'] = $tr->find('td[3] a', 0)->href;
  if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $tr->parent->find('u', 0)->text, $m)){
    list($row['day'], $row['month'], $row['year']) = $m[0];
  }

  // uncomment next 2 lines to save the pdf
  // $filename = preg_replace('/.*\//', '', $row['pdf']);
  // file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($row['pdf']));
  $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows);
```

it shows following error when I inspected further

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/a7944217/public_html/Results.php on line 477 "

var_dump this line `$dom->find('tr.Function_Text_Normal:has(td[3])')` and `$dom` returns null object when dumped shows this object(AdvancedHtmlDom)#1 (6) `{ ["xpath"]=> NULL ["root"]=> NULL ["doc"]=> RECURSION ["dom"]=> NULL ["node"]=> NULL ["is_text"]=> bool(false) }`

`file_get_html` returns null .whats causing this weird behaviour works fine in localhost but not in live server [Page link](http://thewebby.net16.net/Results.php)

Answer (score 2):

You must set "allow_url_fopen" as TRUE in "php.ini" to allow accessing files via HTTP or FTP.
Some hosting venders disable PHP's "allow_url_fopen" flag for security issues.

Or follow the post :[Simple html dom file_get_html not working - is there any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667441/simple-html-dom-file-get-html-not-working-is-there-any-workaround)

Comment: I cannot access the php.ini directly in server as hosting provider did not give me that access

Comment: You will probably need to find a new host.

Comment: @pguardiario  and Navjot Singh  allow_url_fopen is set open by defualt I have checked with their customer care staff

Comment: I imagine there's a long list of things that budget hosts do to prevent things like this, the smart move is to move to a better host.